# Sodium hydroxide reaction with manganese dioxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, redox

I came across a website that said it is possible for sodium hydroxide to react with manganese dioxide at temperatures near 0 degrees Celsius. The reaction goes:
2MnO2 + 3NaOH ⇄ MnO(OH) + Na3MnO4 + H2O
[

Source: https://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-7458
Is this actually a feasible reaction and if so how would one tilt the equilibrium to the right?

Comment: [Chemiday is not a reliable source](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4255). This time, however, they copypasted this reaction from the Russian textbook Lidin, V. A. Molochko, and L. L. Andreeva, *Reactivity of Inorganic Substances*, 3rd ed.; Khimia: Moscow, **2000**, p. 397. How do I know? They didn't bother with proper chemical names and transcribed Russian spelling ("***gipo**manganate*"). Don't use that website. As for the question, the answer is evident if you apply Le Chatelier's principle (hint: temperature aside, $\ce{MnO(OH)}$ is *precipitate*).

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your posts better with MathJax and Markdown.